# Docker e Nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, docker

Tenho uma aplicação em NodeJs e preciso configurar a arquitetura dessa aplicação, sou novo com Docker e preciso criar alguns containers para essa aplicação, a aplicação deve ter a seguinte configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
-- Container 1 - Funciona como um balanceador de carga;
-- Containers 2,3,4  - Instâncias da Aplicação;
-- Container 5 - Banco de dados (Mysql);
```

*OBS: Possivelmente essa arquitetura irá receber mais um container para funcionar como um proxy reverso;*

Gostaria de saber se isso é possível e se sim como fazer o deploy desta aplicação depois ?

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada no [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)!

O Docker Compose é a ferramenta nativa do Docker para lidar com aplicativos que usam múltiplos containers.

Basicamente, você especifica um arquivo 'docker-compose.yml', que identifica quais são os serviços disponibilizados e como eles se relacionam.

Depois é só rodar um comando `docker-compose up` e ele se encarrega de subir os containers necessários.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86379)

Comment: @KennyRafael faz sentido, obrigado pelo correção!

Comment: Eu dei uma olha no docker composer e parece satisfatório no entanto me surgiu uma dúvida, futuramente essa arquitetura vai crescer e se tornar  microserviços que possivelmente estarão em hosts diferentes ainda sim o dokcer composer atenderá minhas necessidades ?

Comment: Uma arquitetura em microserviços implica em outros desafios. O docker compose pode ser usado, mas seria necessário usar tecnologias complementares. Por exemplo, o [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/overview/) para controle de cluster, [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) para descobrimento e health checking dos serviços. Em suma: é viável, mas é um desafio bem maior.